# wordpress code snippet php restricted pages access

Tags: php, wordpress, code-snippets

I'm working on an existing wordpress project and i'm using ultimate member plugin. I think that to restrict access to pages if user is logged or not we have to pay for additional modules. So i tried php code snippets. I tried to use XYZ PHP code snippet but the snippet code is not working although it's active. I think i have to add the snippet created somewhere but don't know where plus the wordpress is in french. Can i go directly to a page edit and add snippet here is the code snippet :

```
<?php
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
wp_redirect( 'https://xxxxir.com/register' ); 
  //auth_redirect();
}
```

> xyz-ips snippet="redirection"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restrict specific page you can do it this way.
Page that you want to restrict should have slug such as `xxx`.

```
// Put these codes in function.php
// xxx is slug of your page

add_action('wp_head', function(){

    global $post;

    $post_slug = $post->post_name;

    if ( $post_slug == 'xxx' && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
      wp_redirect( 'https://xxxxir.com/register' ); 
    }
        
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but i heard that plugin code snippet prevent you to lose the work when you change or update the theme for example. But if i have no choice i'll use this. One question where to find the slug ? The id is in the url in admin but the slug ??

Comment: You can find slug when you edit page. **Edit Page** > **Document** Tab(right sidebar) > **Permalink** > **URL Slug**

Comment: Also you can use **`get_the_ID()`** instead of **post slug**

Comment: It's ok with that but anyone know the function auth_redirect() to return to previous page after login ? We can use it ?